# Matrix norm inequality involving smallest eigenvalue reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, matrix-norms

I search a reference (textbook/paper) for the following symmetric matrix norm inequality.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a real symmetric matrix and let $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ be its eigenvalues. We have that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and for all $\lambda \in \lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$,
\begin{equation}
\|{Ax}\|_{2}\geq |\lambda| \; \|x\|_{2}
\end{equation}
That is, denoting the smallest eigenvalue as $\lambda _{s} = \min_{\lambda \in \left\{  \lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n\right\} } |\lambda|$, $\|Ax\|_{2} \geq \lambda _{s} \|x\|_{2}$.

I can prove this inequality, but I need a textbook/paper proof for reference.. Do you happen to know any?

For completeness, my example verbose proof is:

Since $A$ is symmetric, spectral theorem applies and there exists a unique orthonormal basis formed by eigenvectors $v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}$ of $A$. We obtain the spectral decomposition of $A$:
\begin{equation} 
  A = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i} v_{i}v_{i}^\intercal
\end{equation}
The outer products $v_{i}v_{i}^\intercal$ are the orthogonal projections onto one-dimensional $\lambda _{i}$-eigenspace. Note that
\begin{align*}
 \|Ax\|^{2} & = \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i} v_{i}v_{i}^\intercal x \right)^\intercal  \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i} v_{i}v_{i}^\intercal x \right) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \lambda _{i} x^\intercal v_{i} v_{i}^\intercal \left( \lambda _{i} v_{i} v_{i}^\intercal x + \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \not = i}}^{n} \lambda _{j} v_{j} v_{j}^\intercal x  \right) \right) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i}^{2} x^\intercal v_{i} \underbrace{v_{i}^\intercal v_{i}}_{1} v_{i}^\intercal x  + \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \not = i}}^{n} \lambda _{i} \lambda _{j} x^\intercal v_{i} \underbrace{v_{i}^\intercal v_{j}}_{0} v_{j}^\intercal x\\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i}^{2} ( x^\intercal v_{i} ) ( v_{i}^\intercal x ) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i}^{2} ( v_{i}^\intercal x )^{2}
\end{align*}
Also, given that any $x$ can by expressed as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( v_{i}^\intercal x ) v_{i}$ in the orthonormal base formed by eigenvectors $v_{1},\dots,v_{n}$ (i.e. as vector projections of $x$ onto $v_{i}$),
\begin{align*}
 \|x\|^{2} &= x^\intercal x = \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_{i}( v_{i}^\intercal x )  \right) ^\intercal \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_{i} ( v_{i}^\intercal x ) \right) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( ( x^\intercal v_{i} ) v_{i}^\intercal \left( v_{i}( v_{i}^\intercal x ) + \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \not =i}}^{n} v_{j} (v_{j}^\intercal x)    \right)   \right)  \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( x^\intercal v_{i} ) \underbrace{v_{i}^\intercal v_{i}}_{1} ( v_{i}^\intercal x )  + \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \not =i}}^{n} ( x^\intercal v_{i} ) \underbrace{v_{i}^\intercal v_{j}}_{0} ( v_{j}^\intercal x ) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( x^\intercal v_{i} ) ( v_{i}^\intercal x ) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}  ( v_{i}^\intercal x ) ^{2}
\end{align*}
Now, we get an inequality
\begin{equation}
 \|Ax\|^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda _{i}^{2} ( v_{i}^\intercal x )^{2} \geq \min_{j \in \left\{ 1,..,n \right\} } \lambda _{j}^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( v_{i}^\intercal x ) ^{2} = \min_{j \in \left\{ 1,..,n \right\} } \lambda _{j}^{2} \|x\|^2
\end{equation}

Which after taking the square root finishes the proof.

The reference could have generalized or concise version of this proof, I just can't find anything..

Answer (score 4):

There are some unnecessary steps in your proof. By eliminating them you can simplify it somewhat. Let $\ x_i=v_i^\intercal x\ $. Then $\ x=\sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_iv_i\ $, and
\begin{align}
\|Ax\|^2&=\Big\|A\sum_{i=1}^nx_iv_i\Big\|^2\\
&=\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_iv_i\Big\|^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2x_i^2\\
&\ge\lambda_s^2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\\
&=\lambda_s^2\|x\|^2
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. Do you happen to know any textbook that deals with these types of inequalities? I don't even know what kind of math books cover results like this (I tried googling stuff like matrix norm inequalities eigenvalues but haven't found anything)